# Google Play Games Services for C++ Can't register class

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using Google Play Games Services for C++ version 1.4.1. In my JNI_OnLoad I call

```
gpg::AndroidInitialization::JNI_OnLoad(vm);
```

The call results in the following errors, after which the login doesn't work:

```
05-25 21:49:26.027: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.028: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.028: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/Api: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.028: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$ApiOptions: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.029: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$ApiOptions$HasOptions: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.029: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.030: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$Builder: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.030: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.030: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/Result: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.034: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/ResultCallback: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.034: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/Scope: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.035: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/Status: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.036: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/data/DataBufferUtils: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.036: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Games: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.036: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Games$GamesOptions: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.037: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Games$GamesOptions$Builder: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.037: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Player: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.038: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/PlayerBuffer: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.038: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/PlayerLevel: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.039: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/PlayerLevelInfo: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.040: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Players: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.040: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Players$LoadPlayersResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.041: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievement: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.041: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements$LoadAchievementsResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.042: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/event/Event: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.042: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/event/EventBuffer: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.043: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/event/Events: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.043: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/event/Events$LoadEventsResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.043: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/AchievementBuffer: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.044: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.044: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboard: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.045: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardBuffer: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.045: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.045: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScore: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.046: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScoreBuffer: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.046: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardVariant: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.047: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards$LeaderboardMetadataResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.047: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards$LoadScoresResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.048: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Invitation: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.048: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/InvitationBuffer: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.051: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Invitations: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.052: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Invitations$LoadInvitationsResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.053: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Multiplayer: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.053: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Participant: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.054: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/ParticipantResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.055: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/LoadMatchesResponse: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.055: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatch: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.056: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatchBuffer: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.057: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatchConfig: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.057: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatchConfig$Builder: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.058: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.059: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer$CancelMatchResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.059: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer$InitiateMatchResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.060: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer$LeaveMatchResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.060: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer$LoadMatchesResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.061: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer$LoadMatchResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.061: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer$UpdateMatchResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.061: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Quest: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.062: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/QuestBuffer: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.062: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Quests: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.062: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Milestone: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.063: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Quests$LoadQuestsResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.063: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Quests$AcceptQuestResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.064: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Quests$ClaimMilestoneResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.064: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshot: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.065: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/SnapshotContents: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.065: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/SnapshotMetadata: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.065: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/SnapshotMetadataBuffer: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.066: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.068: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots$CommitSnapshotResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.069: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots$LoadSnapshotsResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.070: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots$OpenSnapshotResult: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.070: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/SnapshotMetadataChange: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.071: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/SnapshotMetadataChange$Builder: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.071: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RealTimeMessageReceivedListener: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.072: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RealTimeMultiplayer: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.073: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RealTimeMessage: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.074: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/Room: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.074: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomConfig: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.075: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomConfig$Builder: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.076: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/appstate/AppStateManager: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.077: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/Nearby: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.077: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/AppIdentifier: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.078: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/AppMetadata: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.078: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/Connections: an exception occurred.
05-25 21:49:26.079: E/GamesNativeSDK(18597): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/Connections$StartAdvertisingResult: an exception occurred.
```

Googling the issue didn't yield much result. There seemed to have been a [similar issue with the Unity plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/298) and [this blog isn't helping much](http://blogs.pkstate.com/2014/09/09-07-231219520-egamesnativesdk5012.html).

Why is this error happening? Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 2):

These errors are caused by the google-play-services jar file not being part of your application. The steps are laid out on https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/gettingStartedAndroid
 Things to check:

1. You project includes the google-play-services.jar and android-support-v4.jar file (and they are included in the apk file).
2. That it is a recent version of the library (at least version 22, but the latest is preferred).  You can use the SDK manager to download the latest.

Comment: The instructions you linked don't mention any jar files. The C++ SDK doesn't include any jar files. Are they really needed? I will try to get my hands on those and see what happens.

Comment: I downloaded google play services with Android SDK Manager and copied it over to my Android project's libs folder. This fixed the problem with the init. Thanks you.

Comment: Actually, you are not supposed to put the google-play-services.jar in your project. You are supposed to link to the library, as explained here: https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance someone comes across that subject but didn't solve his issue, here's how I fixed mine: I change my Proguard configuration so it does not strip any classes from the `com.google.android` package.

Ie: 
from `-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }` to `-keep public class com.google.android.gms.** { public *; }`

---

You may also need to activate multiDex in your `build.gradle` file with the following lines: 
`buildTypes {
    yourBuildType_Eg_release {
        multiDexEnabled true
            dexOptions {
                preDexLibraries false
                incremental true // that's a big heap!
                javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            }
        }
    }`